# Nested LinearLayouts inside ScrollView inside ConstraintLayout best practise

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a layout where I was using Constraintlayout and it was working fine with 4 horizontial Linearlayouts all with there own subviews.  There is an imageview at the top of the screen and adview at the bottom.

It was looking fine on large screens but obviously not on small screens so I placed the 4 horizontial Linearlayouts inside a Vertical Linearlayout that is inside a ScrollView.

Its working fine but I am uncertain if this is the correct way to acomplish this tasks.  I would of liked to add a constraint for the internal horizontial Linearlayouts but had to settle for match parent for width and set the height along with margins.

Is this approach correct or is there a better way?

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    tools:context="au.com.xxxxxx.xxxxx.Activities.MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/fish_in_wave" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="56dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="354dp">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/closest"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:elevation="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="40dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="40dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                    android:paddingRight="40dp"
                    android:paddingStart="40dp"
                    android:paddingTop="40dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/near_me_white_24dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="35dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="161dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fsNearMe"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:elevation="10dp"
                    android:text="Show closest fishing spots."
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textIsSelectable="false"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="107dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="256dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="54dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="451dp">


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/browseby"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:elevation="10dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/map_white_24dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="35dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="255dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fsByState"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@id/fsNearMe"
                    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:elevation="10dp"
                    android:text="Browse known fishing spots"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="123dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="244dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="54dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="551dp">


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/addOwn"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:elevation="10dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/add_location_white_24dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="185dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/addMyMap"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@id/fsByState"
                    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:elevation="10dp"
                    android:text="Add your own fishing spots"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="107dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="355dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="67dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="629dp">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/notes"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:elevation="10dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/note_add_white_24dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="35dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="449dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/addMyNotes"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:elevation="10dp"
                    android:text="Notes and Pictures"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="@string/UNIT_ID"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: you can use RecyclerView instead

Comment: I thought that might be a way to do it too.  Appreciate the suggestion.